# when to add indexes to tables?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a many-to-many relationship database with 3 tables. It's very slow to load the data into the tables, especially the join table. Several hours for 3 millions rows.

I was suggested to create the tables first without creating index. I am using Hibernate. If I don't annotate index in classes, then what's the best time and way to add index? Should I do it directly on MySql database using SQL statement? Or the index should be added somewhere in Hibernate, without affecting loading performance?

Comment: It sounds like you might be confusing two separate concepts; an index is not the same as a hint. You need to add some indices, but you probably should not add any hints.

Comment: When is the best place and time to add index, if the data loading is very slow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add indexes directly to MySQL database using CREATE INDEX statement.
If you have very big table you can use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) to prevent blocking your application